# Date format when importing from MySQL Date into the Textbox C#.NET

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, date

So I'm populating a DATE field in MySQL table from the DateTimePicker and on the other form I need to show the date in the textbox in "dd.MM.yyyy" format, but for some reason it populates the textbox in "MM/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS" format.

I'm populating it simply like this:

```
tbDate.Text = dt.Rows[0][14].ToString();
```

How do i change the format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code

```
tbDate.Text = ((DateTime)dt.Rows[0][14]).ToString("dd.M.yyyy");
```

Comment: Perfect! That's what I've tried to do right away, but without (DateTime), thanks, workes like a charm! =)

Answer (score 3):

> I need to show the date in the textbox in "dd.MM.yyyy" format

you need to first cast the value into `DateTime` type and then pass your [`Custom Date Format String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to the `ToString()` function

Try This:

```
tbDate.Text = ((DateTime) dt.Rows[0][14]).ToString("dd.MM.yyyy");
```

Comment: It may throw an exception if the date in the row is not in the required format, so it is not advised at all.

Comment: @AbdulRahmanAnsari: what do you mean by `if the date in the row is not in the required format`?

Comment: As the date is coming from database, hence its format can't be determined. It can be in any format like `yyyy/mm/dd` or `dd/mm/yyyy`. Hence the while casting that to `DateTime` may throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the format in your C# code, directly fetch the date in the required format from database.

You can use the following query to fetch the date in `dd.MM.yyyy` format

```
select DATE_FORMAT(date_column,'%d.%m.%Y') FROM table_name;
```

Please refer this [**SQLFiddle Example**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a79404/8)

And then you can use your following code as it is,

```
tbDate.Text = dt.Rows[0][14].ToString();
```

Hope this helps :)